# mysql show oldest date from the table

Tags: php, mysql, date

In mysql I have the table like this

```
id  name end_date
1   test1  2014-09-20
2   test1  2014-09-23
3   test1  2014-09-28
4   test1  2014-09-21
```

here I want to get the oldest date for the end_date. In this table you can see I have the oldest date is 
2014-09-28. So can someone tell me how to get the oldest date from the table

Comment: What is the type of `end_date`?

Comment: Something like `GROUP BY name ORDER BY min(end_date)` should work. Maybe even add `ASC`

Comment: `SELECT name, MIN(end_date) FROM YourTable GROUP by name`

Comment: just select it normally ordered by end_date asc limit 1, should be the oldest according the date

Comment: you say datetime, but that's not the format displayed i would expect 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: I think you meant to say the __newest__ date.

Comment: yeah contradicting: `2014-09-28` is the latest, not the oldest

Answer (score 2):

`2014-09-21` is the **newest** date in your table. Use the `MAX` aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(end_date)
FROM tblName
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the "oldest" date value from a column in the table, if that's a DATE datatype, or a VARCHAR a CHAR stored in canonical format, there;s a couple of approaches. One is to use the `MIN()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT MIN(t.end_date) AS oldest_end_date FROM mytable t ;
```

To get the most recent date, you could use the corresponding `MAX()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT MIN(t.end_date) AS newest_end_date FROM mytable t ;
```

Another approach is to use an ORDER BY clause, in either ascending or descending order by end_date, with a LIMIT clause to restrict the number of rows returned

```
SELECT t.end_date FROM mytable t ORDER BY t.end_date ASC LIMIT 1 ;
SELECT t.end_date FROM mytable t ORDER BY t.end_date DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

If you want to return more than just the oldest "end_date" value, you want additional columns from the row that contains that "end_date", you could just modify the SELECT list of the ORDER BY LIMIT queries above.

There are some performance issues to be considered with large sets; having an appropriate index available can improve performance of some of the possible queries you might use.